# Unable to find an active editor state using webpack serve

Tags: webpack, lexicaljs

Until recently, i used react-scripts to run my react project based on lexical.But now i need to implement it as a module of my main project. To do this, i configured webpack to build it for a production purpose as a module and run webpack serve to debug it. It gave me severe headaches and now that it almost done i have an ultime bug when i run webpack serve : "Unable to find an active editor state. State helpers or node methods can only be used synchronously during the callback of editor.update() or editorState.read().". It does not occure when i run "react-scripts start".

the bug seems to be at this line (861) in Lexical.dev.js :

[VS Code Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1gox.png)

The error:

```
Unable to find an active editor state. State helpers or node methods can only be used synchronously during the callback of editor.update() or editorState.read().
at getActiveEditorState (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/lexical/Lexical.dev.js:8973:13)
at $getRoot (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/lexical/Lexical.dev.js:887:26)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/lexical/Lexical.dev.js:861:33)
at readEditorState (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/lexical/Lexical.dev.js:9211:12)
at EditorState.read (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/lexical/Lexical.dev.js:10559:12)
at getEditorStateTextContent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/lexical/Lexical.dev.js:861:22)
at triggerTextContentListeners (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/lexical/Lexical.dev.js:9413:30)
at commitPendingUpdates (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/lexical/Lexical.dev.js:9399:3)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/lexical/Lexical.dev.js:9686:9)
```

my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "@robothoustra/texteditor",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/IndexEditor.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src/features",
    "src/components"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/robothoustra/texteditor"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "restricted"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@excalidraw/excalidraw": "^0.14.2",
    "@lexical/clipboard": "0.11.3",
    "@lexical/code": "0.11.3",
    "@lexical/file": "0.11.3",
    "@lexical/hashtag": "0.11.3",
    "@lexical/link": "0.11.3",
    "@lexical/list": "0.11.3",
    "@lexical/mark": "0.11.3",
    "@lexical/overflow": "0.11.3",
    "@lexical/plain-text": "0.11.3",
    "@lexical/react": "^0.11.3",
    "@lexical/rich-text": "0.11.3",
    "@lexical/selection": "0.11.3",
    "@lexical/table": "0.11.3",
    "@lexical/utils": "0.11.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.7",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.1",
    "katex": "^0.16.8",
    "lexical": "^0.11.1",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "match-sorter": "^6.3.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "natural": "^6.5.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "react-window": "^1.8.9",
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "y-websocket": ">=1.3.x",
    "yjs": ">=13.5.42"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.20",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.8",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.8",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development --config webpack.config.dev.js",
    "build:dev": "webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js",
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

my webpack.config.dev.json :

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js', // Entry point of your React application,
    mode: "development",
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        crypto: false, // require.resolve("crypto-browserify") can be polyfilled here if needed
        stream: false, // require.resolve("stream-browserify") can be polyfilled here if needed
        assert: false, // require.resolve("assert") can be polyfilled here if needed
        http: false, // require.resolve("stream-http") can be polyfilled here if needed
        https: false, // require.resolve("https-browserify") can be polyfilled here if needed
        os: false, // require.resolve("os-browserify") can be polyfilled here if needed
        url: false, // require.resolve("url") can be polyfilled here if needed
        zlib: false, // require.resolve("browserify-zlib") can be polyfilled here if needed
        fs: false,
      },   
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
      fullySpecified: false,
    },
    // devtool: "eval",
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    optimization: {
      portableRecords: true,
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
      module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/, // Match JavaScript files
          exclude: /node_modules/, // Exclude node_modules
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader', // Use Babel for JavaScript transpilation
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: 'ts-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },  
        {
          test: /\.css$/, // Match CSS files
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'], // Handle CSS files
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|jp2|webp|ico)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './public/index.html',
        favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
        'process.env.NODE_DEBUG': JSON.stringify(false),
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      port: 3000, // Port for development server
      hot: true,
      open: true,
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map', // Enable source maps for easier debugging
    ignoreWarnings: [
      {
        module: /classifiers/,
      },
      /warning from compiler/,
      (warning) => true,
    ],  
};
```

i tried to remove all the plugins my text editor implement but it seems it is a general issue. I had a previous bug with react that disappeared when i added "window.React = React;" to my index.js. Maybe it s a kind of the same issue. But really don't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Lexical maintains a variable called `activeEditor` in the file **Lexical.dev.js** in the node_modules folder.

If you have `lexical` installed in both the folder where you run **webpack** and the **folder where you consume your bundled custom lexical library**, issues with resolving the file housing the current `activeEditor` may arise. Since they both have `activeEditor` values that they track independently.

Issue arise when the code execution process is initiated by a file which houses the `activeEditor` variable (let's call it `file A`) in webpack's folder and subsequently, a function call is made that takes the code execution process out of `file A` to another file (`file B`) which is still in the webpack's folder. But then on completion of `file B`'s task, instead of returning to `file A`, the execution process goes to an identical file (`file C`) located in the folder where you consume your custom lexical bundle. Thus causing the `activeEditor` to be reinitiated and as a result of the reinitialization, your editor is reported as inactive.

**Possible solution:**

Utilize webpack's `externals` configuration option by adding the below to the webpack's config

```
module.exports = {
    // Other configuration options ...
    externals: ["lexical", /^@lexical\/.+$/],
};
```

According to webpack:

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding
> dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle
> relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's (any
> end-user application) environment. This feature is typically most
> useful to library developers, however there are a variety of
> applications for it.

In this case, you tell webpack that the lexical modules will be provided by consumer's dependencies.

More info [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals)

This will prevent webpack from bundling lexical alongside your other files.

You can then go on to remove lexical from the dependencies in the folder you run webpack by running `npm remove lexical`

This is to ensure that only one source of truth exists which is your **consumer folder's node_modules files**

Also, instead of spinning a webserver using webpack, you can convert your bundles to a webpack library and import the files like any other library out there

This involves making these configuration changes

```
module.exports = {
    // Other configuration options ...
    output: {
        // Other output options...
        library: {
            name: "Your Custom Library Name",
            type: "umd",
        },
    },
    // Your new externals option
    externals: ["lexical", /^@lexical\/.+$/],
};
```